# Using link_to to add url params when not using a path helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using link_to to build my URL and I'm doing this kind of stuff

```
<%= link_to "new wire", [:new, @object, @post], :class => 'green', ...
```

But how would I add url params through link_to? For example I want the URL to be

```
http://www.something.com/groups/3/posts/4?a_param=23
```

without having to use the new_group_post_path(@group, @post, :a_param => '23') helper.

UPDATE:

Just to be more clear, I don't know what @object is, it could be a Group object, Member object etc, nor do I want to use a long and binding if/elsif/elsif...end condition to locate which object in turn to know what url helper (ie new_group_post_path() or new_member_post_path() ...) therefore the reason for having Rails guess the URL for me using the array struct shown above ie.[@object, @post...].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= link_to "new wire", polymorphic_path([:new, @object, @post], a_param: '23', b_param: '24'), :class => 'green', ...
```

Refer [polymorphic_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_path) for details.

Comment: Wha!!! Amazing, many thanks, I've searched that one for a long time since this current project has tons of polymorphic objects, go figure, it's even named after it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it in as a hash to your url helper in link_to:

```
<%= link_to "new wire", new_object_url(@object, :a_param => 23), :method=> :post, :class => 'green', ...
```

Comment: I added an additional explanation because I'm assuming your answer didn't understand that I don't know what the object is in this case, and therefore don't know what url helper to use. See above.